# How to show different texts on x-axis ticks and on chart hover in Google column chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to show different texts on x-axis ticks and in tooltip, I tried setting up tick object in my data as {v: '2010', f: 'abc'}, but google column chart uses 'f' property for both axis label and tooltip. I want it to use 'v' for tooltip and 'f' for labels on x-axis.
Is there any option available to achieve this. Below is my simple reproduceable example.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {


      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General',
         'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
        [{v: '2010', f: 'abc'}, 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
        [{v: '2020', f: 'deg'}, 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ''],
        [{v: '2030', f: 'ghi'}, 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, '']
      ]);

      var options = {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
        bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
        isStacked: true,
        hAxis: {
          format: function (val) {
            console.log('val', val);
          }
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
        document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0Luock3y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using a string for the value: `'2010'`
you'll need to use a number: `2010`

this will allow you to customize the ticks in the options...

```
hAxis: {
  ticks: [{v: 2010, f: 'abc'}, {v: 2020, f: 'deg'}, {v: 2030, f: 'ghi'}]
}
```

`hAxis.ticks` does not work when the x-axis value is a string

as for the tooltip, you can use the number value,
but here, I included the object notation,
so a comma is not displayed in the tooltip: `2,010`

```
[{v: 2010, f: '2010'}, 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {


      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Genre', 'Fantasy & Sci Fi', 'Romance', 'Mystery/Crime', 'General',
         'Western', 'Literature', { role: 'annotation' } ],
        [{v: 2010, f: '2010'}, 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ''],
        [{v: 2020, f: '2020'}, 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ''],
        [{v: 2030, f: '2030'}, 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, '']
      ]);

      var options = {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
        bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
        isStacked: true,
        hAxis: {
          ticks: [{v: 2010, f: 'abc'}, {v: 2020, f: 'deg'}, {v: 2030, f: 'ghi'}]
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
        document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```